# how to add dynamic value in apache tiles from controller in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, apache-tiles

tiles

```
   <definition name="home" extends="container">
            <put-attribute name="title" expression="${modal.title}" />
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/masters/home.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="view" value="home" />
        </definition>
```

this is my method in controller

```
@RequestMapping("/home/{linkAddress}")
    public String homeDt(
            @PathVariable(value="linkAddress") String linkAddress,Model model){
        HomeMt homeMt = homeMtService.findByLink(linkAddress);
        model.addAttribute("contentOne", homeMt.getContentOne());
        model.addAttribute("title", "ronaldo");
        model.addAttribute("homeMt", homeMt);
        return "home";
    }
```

[image]

**my problem is that the title value is not coming in the jsp page**,
some say that enable the el support but it didn't worked for me.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of title as `${title}` instead of `${modal.title}`

Comment: Yes i had tried that and it was printing ${title} instead of ronaldo

Comment: did you find any solution?